# Footer Fade in and then out

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to have a footer that stays fixed at the bottom of the page and only fades in when the mouse goes over it and then fades out once the mouse is not over it but I cant seem to get it to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/PDeqM/

HTML

```
<footer>
Footer stuff
</footer>​
```

CSS:

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    display: none;
    background: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    color: #fff
}​
```

Jquery

```
$("footer").hover(
            function(){
                $(this).fadeIn(100);
            },
            function(){
                $(this).fadeOut(100);
            }
);​
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's hidden you can't hover it.  Try using opacity:

```
$("footer").css({'opacity':0}).hover(
    function(){
        $(this).animate({'opacity':1},100);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).animate({'opacity':0},100);
    }
);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PDeqM/6/

Answer (score 0):

You have to animate its opacity, not its visibility, as running `fadeOut()` makes it disappear at the end.

This code works:

```
$('footer').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 100);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 100);
}).css('opacity', 0);​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PDeqM/8/**

Answer (score 0):

User opacity instead of display.

http://jsfiddle.net/PDeqM/9/